# Why is bam from mgcv slow for some data?

Tags: r, performance, regression, gam, mgcv

I am fitting the same Generalized Additive Model on multiple data sets using the `bam` function from `mgcv`. While for most of my data sets the fit completes within a reasonable time between 10 and 20 minutes. For a few data sets the run take more than 10 hours to complete. I cannot find any similarities between the slow cases, the final fit is neither exceptionally good nor bad, nor do they contain any noticeable outliers.

How can I figure out why the fit is so slow for these instances? And how might I be able to speed these up?

My model contains two smooth terms (using a cyclic  cubic spline basis) and some additional numerical and factor variables. In total 300 coefficients (including those for smooth terms) are estimated. I keep the number of knots intentionally below information theoretically optimal numbers to speed up the fitting process. My data sets contain around 850k rows.

This is the function call:

```
bam(
    value
    ~ 0
    + weekday_x
    + weekday
    + time
    + "a couple of factor variables encoding special events"
    + delta:weekday
    + s(share_of_year, k=length(knotsYear), bs="cc")
    + s(share_of_year_x, k=length(knotsYear), bs="cc")
    , knots=list(
      share_of_year=knotsYear
      , share_of_year_x=knotsYear
    )
    , family=quasipoisson()
    , data=data
)
```

knotsYears contains 26 knots.

This model converges reasonably fast for most cases but incredibly slow for a few.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## A most likely cause: "fREML" failure

In a typical model like above, without tensor smooth `te` or `ti`, my experience is that REML iteration fails for some cases.

The canonical `bam` implementation uses `fast.REML.fit`. The convergence test of this routine needs a fix, but as Simon has moved on and focus more on the `discrete` method now, he is not keen on fixing it. The fixed version is (at the moment) only available in an extension pack for testing, "Zheyuan add-on", supplemented to my PhD thesis. But `fast.REML.fit` is also not that fragile, and such convergence failure is not often, otherwise piles of big report would get this issue fixed back in 2012.

The following just helps you make a check not a fix.

Let `fit` be your fitted model that takes 10 hours, check `fit$outer.info`. This gives number of REML iterations it takes, and the convergence information like gradient and Hessian. If you see `iter = 200`, or any information saying some failure like "step failed", then you know why it takes so long. But if you look at gradient, most likely you will see that it is almost zero. In other words, REML iteration has actually converged but `fast.REML.fit` fails to detect it.

---

## Another check: "performance iteration"

Since you are fitting a GAM not an AM (additive model with Gaussian response), there is another P-IRLS (penalized iteratively re-weighed least squares) outside the REML iteration. Yes, the whole (canonical) `bam` estimation is a double loop nest, called "performance iteration". This may fail, too, but such failure is more intrinsic and may not be overcome, as the "performance iteration" is not guaranteed to converge. So, check `fit$iter` to see if it is also very big (in the worst case it can be 200). `mgcv` manual has a dedicated section `?gam.convergence` discussing this type of convergence failure, and it is the driving reason that "outer iteration" is desirable. However, for large dataset, "outer iteration" is too expensive to implement. So, bear with "performance iteration".

`mgcv` has a "tracing" option. If you set `control = gam.control(trace = TRUE)` when calling `bam`, the deviance information and iteration counter will be printed to screen as "performance iteration" goes. This gives you a clear path of the penalized deviance, so you can inspect whether it is cycling around or trapped at some point. This is more informative than a single iteration number stored in `fit$iter`.

---

## Perhaps try the new method?

Maybe you want to try the new `discrete = TRUE` (added in 2015; paper formally published in 2017). It uses a new fitting iteration. We are (MUCH) happier to test its practical convergence capability, than the old method. When using it, turn on "trace", too. If it fails to converge, think about reporting it, but we need a reproducible case.